# Python ModuleNotFoundError when executing script directly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have browsed over a lot of questions on this topic, and I have found a lot of information, but I am still unable to fully understand what is happening and how to solve my problem

This is the question:

I am using python3.9.5, and I have the following layout:

```
root_folder/
    src/
       a.py
       b.py
```

Inside `a.py` I have:

```py
from src.b import do_something_B

def do_something_A():
    do_something_B()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_something_A()
```

An `b.py`:

```py
def do_something_B():
    print("Hello from B")
```

If I run Ipython REPL, I can do:

```py
from src.a import do_something_A
do_something_A() # this prints "Hello from B" without errors
```

But if I try to execute a.py from console I get the following output:

```
❯ python src/a.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alejo/playground/root_folder/src/a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.b import do_something_B
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Creating a `__init__.py` file inside `src` folder does not make any difference

What am I understanding wrong?

***EDIT***

If I change `a.py` to import b without src namespace (changing first line to `from b import do_something_B`) then I can execute the script from bash, but it fails when I try to use it with iPython REPL

Comment: When you run a script from the command line, the module import path will include _the directory where the script lives_, not _the current directory_.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the directory as the two files are in the same directory already.

Simply do `from b import do_something_B` and it should work.

Same thing in `b.py`

Also to clarify, using `src.someFunc` implies that there is a *module* named `src` not that there is a *directory* named `src`.

Look into absolute imports if you need to import across directories, which in this case you do not, so don't worry.

Comment: If I do that, it works when I execute the python script directly with bash, but it raise a `ModuleNotFoundError` when using iPython REPL

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question browsing the documentation:

Quoting https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

*When a module named spam is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable sys.path. sys.path is initialized from these locations:*

- ***The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).***
- *PYTHONPATH (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).*
- *The installation-dependent default.*

As I am specifiying an script, **the folder of the script** is added to `sys.path`, not the current folder

I would need to add a `c.py` file directly in `root_folder` than imports `src.a` and executes `do_something_A()` to be able to call it from bash